# Firebase - Deploy Your Site - Deletes Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

### Question

How can I deploy my Firebase site without erasing Cloud Functions.

1. Maybe, include both site and cloud-functions in one deploy? What does that look like?
2. Maybe, deploy the site without erasing cloud-functions? I don't find a `firebase deploy --only site` or similar

### Context

I have a Firebase project that uses Cloud Functions. The code is in two folders:

```
-site-code
-cloud_function-code
```

When I want to deploy the project, I use firebase CLI tools, in two steps:

**Step 1**

from `-site-code` I run:

```
firebase deploy
```

**Step 2**

then from `cloud_functions-code` I run:

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

### Issue

When I run `firebase deploy` *from* `-site-code`, my Firebase Cloud Functions are deleted, so I must follow up with `firebase deploy --only functions` *from* `-cloud_functions-code`.

I did not find an `--only` directive for deploying just the site code from `-site-code`

Comment: Running `firebase deploy --except functions` will deploy just the site. As will `firebase deploy --only hosting`

Comment: Alternatively to the two already mentioned: `firebase deploy --only hosting`, which would only deploy hosting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To only deploy your web site, use

```
firebase deploy --only hosting
```

Answer (score 3):

The Firebase CLI provides a way to deploy single functions as shown in its [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#partial_deploys):

```
firebase deploy --only functions:name_of_function
```